# why the token parameter in verify function is showing error in jwt authentitcation?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, jwt, express-jwt

> I am trying to do jwt authentication and i am getting error like this on verify function.
>
> > No overload matches this call.
> > Overload 1 of 3, '(token: string, secretOrPublicKey: Secret, options?: VerifyOptions | undefined): string | object', gave the following error.
> > Argument of type 'string | string[] | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
> > Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
> > Overload 2 of 3, '(token: string, secretOrPublicKey: Secret | GetPublicKeyOrSecret, callback?: VerifyCallback | undefined): void', gave the following error.

```
import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from "express";
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";
import config from "../config/default"

var authorization = function (req:Request, res:Response, next:NextFunction) {
    var token = req.headers['x-access-token'];
    var msg = {auth: false, message: 'No token provided.'};

    if (!token) res.status(500).send(msg);

    jwt.verify(token, config.token.secret, function (err) {
        var msg = {auth: false, message: 'Failed to authenticate token.'};
        if (err) res.status(500).send(msg);
        next();
    });
}

module.exports = authorization;
```

Comment: It is coming because either of your values `token` or `secret` might be undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `req.headers` returns value of type `string | string[] | undefined`. And you're trying to pass it as an argument to the function expecting type `string` in that position. Thus the error.

There are some issues with your code you have to address to fix it:

- after `if (!token) res.status(500).send(msg)` function execution does not stop. It will proceed to the `jwt.verify`. Though it won't pass token check with falsy token it will run the verify function anyway. This condition **does not** narrow the type.

```ts
declare const n: number | null

if (!n) {
  console.log('0, NaN or null')
} else {
  type N = typeof n // N ~ number
}

if (!n) console.log('0, NaN or null')

type M = typeof n // M ~ number | null
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/N7bABw)

- `token` may be an array of strings

---

For your code to typecheck and work correctly you have to [narrow](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) the type of `token` to `string`:

```ts
import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from "express";
import jwt, { VerifyErrors } from "jsonwebtoken";
import config from "../config/default"

var authorization = function (req:Request, res:Response, next:NextFunction) {
    var token = req.headers['x-access-token'];
    var msg = {auth: false, message: 'No token provided.'};

    // check whether `token` is an array and get the first element
    // narrows the type to `string | undefined`
    if (Array.isArray(token)) token = token[0];

    // narrows the type to `string`
    if (!token) {
      res.status(500).send(msg);
      // return early and prevent execution of the underlying middlewares
      return next(false); 
    }

    jwt.verify(token, config.token.secret, function (err: VerifyErrors | null) {
        var msg = {auth: false, message: 'Failed to authenticate token.'};
        if (err) res.status(500).send(msg);
        next();
    });
}

module.exports = authorization;
```